# Html-Search box that links to websites through key words

Tags: html, forms, search, input, hyperlink

So recently I have been working on my websites and I wanted a way users can easily get to one website to another without messy links. So I wanted to add a text entry box so that if the user types in a key word such as "Forums", it would act as clicking a link and take them to that site. Here is my current text entry box code. (PS: I do not want to use javascript, I just want html).

```
<form action="action_page.php">
Website Search:<br>
<input type="text" name="Website Search" value="website name here">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do it without javascript is php.

Here is a sample that should work:

HTML:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
Website Search:<br>
<input type="text" id="Website Search" name="Website Search" placeholder="website name here">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

action_page.php:

```
$word = $_POST["Website Search"];
$word = strtolower($word); //converts the word to lowercase

$link_forum = ""; //write the link to the pages here
$link_page1 = "";
$link_page2 = "";

if ($word == "forum") {
    header("location:".$link_forum); //this redirects you to the page.
}
elseif ($word == "page1") {
    header("location:".$link_page1);
}
elseif ($word == "page2") {
    header("location:".$link_page2);
}
```

Just add as many pages as you need and this should work just fine.